# Is the inverse of a nonzero intertwining operator in Schur's lemma bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, representation-theory

**Definition**. Let $G$ be any topological group. A representation of $G$ on a nonzero complex Hilbert space $V$ is a group homomorphism $\pi$ of $G$ into the group $GL(V)$ of bounded linear operators on $V$ with bounded inverses, such that the resulting map $G\times V\to V$ given by $(g,v)\mapsto \pi(g)v$ is continuous.

**Schur's lemma**. Let $G$ be a topological group. Let $V_1$ and $V_2$ be nonzero complex Hilbert spaces. Suppose $(\pi_1,V_1)$ and $(\pi_2,V_2)$ are any two irreducible unitary representations of $G$. Let $T: V_1\to V_2$ be a bounded linear operator such that $T\pi_1(g)=\pi_2(g)T$ for all $g\in G$. Then if $T\neq 0$ then $T$ is invertible.

Well-known proof is as follows:

$Proof.$  If $x\in \operatorname{Ker}T$ then we have $T\pi_1(g)x=\pi_2(g)Tx=0$ for all $g\in G$. So the closed subspace $\operatorname{Ker}T$ of $V_1$ is invariant under $\pi_1$. By the irreducibility of $\pi_1$, we must have $\operatorname{Ker}T=0$ since $T\neq 0$. On the other hand, if $y\in \operatorname{Im}T$ then there is some $x\in T$ such that $Tx=y$. For $g\in G$, we get $\pi_2(g)y=\pi_2(g)Tx=T\pi_1(g)x$, which implies that $\operatorname{Im}T$ is invariant under $\pi_2$. By the irreducibility of $\pi_2$, we must have $\operatorname{Im}T=V_2$ since $T\neq 0$. So $T$ is invertible.

**My question**: Can we also conclude that $T^{-1}$ is a bounded linear operator? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The open mapping theorem implies that any bijective bounded linear operator between Banach spaces has a bounded inverse. This will answer your question.

But the proof you wrote is in fact wrong. You may only conclude that the image is *dense*, since the closure of the image is a **closed** invariant subspace. So what you need to show is that the image of $T$ is already closed. To do this, consider the bounded linear intertwiner $S:=T^{\ast} \circ T: V_1 \rightarrow V_1$, where $T^{\ast}: V_2 \rightarrow V_1$ is the adjoint operator. By what is also known as "Schur's Lemma", one gets $S = \lambda \text{id}_{V_1}$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbf{C}$. By the assumption that $T \neq 0$, there is a vector $v_1 \in V_1$ with $Tv_1 \neq 0$, which satisfies
$$
\lambda \langle v_1, v_1 \rangle_{V_1} = \langle Sv_1 , v_1 \rangle_{V_1} = \langle Tv_1, Tv_1 \rangle_{V_2} > 0\,.
$$
Hence $\lambda > 0$ and it follows that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}T: V_1 \rightarrow V_2$ is an **isometric** $G$-morphism. Therefore, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}T$ and $T$ have closed images.